# Incorrect ktable aggregation after enabling rocksdb compression

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

To optimize space we enabled snappy compression for state store (rocks db).
We noticed that after enabling compression our aggregation calculation were incorrect. We are not able to find why enabling the compression can cause this.

```
Rocks db config
100mb block cache size
16mb block size
Max write buffer number - 2
Cacheindexandfilterblocks - true
```

I can say that its because of compression because we removed compression and it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of concerning. LZ4 is a comparable (some would say better) compression to snappy that rocksdb/Streams also supports, if you try using that do you still see the same thing?

If so, try clearing the state for your Streams app and restarting. You should actually be able to reopen rocksdb instances with different compression types but maybe something got corrupted?